# Ruby on Rails Why do I get this error message when changing the amount shown per page with multi-find?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, search, resultset

In my ruby on rails application I have a drop down menu on the index page where a user can change the amount of results displayed, for example changing from 6 results to 3 results. It works on the index.html.erb page when the application loads, but when the search is used and relevant results are returned changing the results shown per page I get the following error:

TypeError in ProductsController#multi_find
   can't convert nil into String

```
Extracted source (around line #64):

62 def self.multi_find(cat_id, search)
63 search_price = search
64 search_condition = "%" + search + "%"
65 # test if cat_id is not blank
66 if not cat_id.blank?
67 # assign the value of cat_id to a ‘scope’ named :cat
```

This is the drop down menu in the index.html.erb file:

```
                <div id="per-page">
                    <form>
                        Results per page:
                        <select name="per">
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                        </select>
                        <button>
                            Go
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

This is the products_controller where the results per page is added to the index:

```
  def index
     @products = Product.order(:title).page(params[:page]).per(params.fetch(:per, '6').to_i)
 end
```

This is the multi_find method in the products_controller where using the drop down menu breaks:

```
  def multi_find
    # call a Product class method, using two parameters; a category unique identifier and a search string (author or title)
    products = Product.multi_find(params[:cat_id], params[:search_string])
    @products = Kaminari.paginate_array(products.order :title).page(params[:page]).per(params.fetch(:per, '6').to_i)
    # if no products have been found
    if products.empty?
        # display a notice
        flash.now[:alert] = "No records found - displaying all records ..." 
        # then display all products
        @products = Product.order(:title).page(params[:page]).per(params.fetch(:per, '6').to_i)
    end
    # use the index view
    render :action => "index" 
end
```

And the product.rb multi_find method:

```
    def self.multi_find(cat_id, search)
    search_price = search
    search_condition = "%" + search + "%"
    # test if cat_id is not blank
    if not cat_id.blank?
        # assign the value of cat_id to a ‘scope’ named :cat 
        scope :cat, -> { where('category_id = ?', cat_id)}
        # using the ‘scope’ cat find where a search string is like a title or an author’s name
        self.cat.where("title LIKE ? OR author_name LIKE ? OR price = ?", search_condition, search_condition, search_price)
    # else
    else
        # find where a search string is like a title or an author’s name
         self.cat.where("title LIKE ? OR author_name LIKE ? OR price = ?", search_condition, search_condition, search_price)
    # end
    end
```

If I completely remove the:

```
.per(params.fetch(:per, '6').to_i)
```

And just use .per(6) it works fine, it's only when replacing it to try and allow the user to select the amount per page with the multi_find search it breaks.

Can anyone help? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because `search` in the last line here:

```
def self.multi_find(cat_id, search)
  search_price = search
  search_condition = "%" + search + "%"
```

...is equal to nil.  That means when you do this:

```
Product.multi_find(params[:cat_id], params[:search_string])
```

...`params[:search_string]` has to be nil.  You didn't post any html that has a name attribute equal to 'search_string'.

Nevertheless, if this is true:

> If I completely remove the:
>
> ```
> .per(params.fetch(:per, '6').to_i)
> ```
>
> And just use .per(6) it works fine,
>   it's only when replacing it to try and allow the user to select the
>   amount per page with the multi_find search it breaks.

Then instead of cramming so much code into one line, sort out the parameter value before you stick it in .per():

```
period_from_select = params[:per] 
puts "*****period_from_select=#{period_from_select}"  #look in the server window for this output

if period_from_select
  period_from_select = period_from_select.to_i
else
  period_from_select = 6
end

puts "****period_from_select=#{period_from_select}"

...per(period_from_select)
```

Comment: Ok, so what should I change the code to? Sorry, I'm fairly new to RoR

Comment: @benjs.1, Do you even have a form field named 'search_string'?

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't think so

Comment: Then what value is `params[:search_string]` supposed to be retrieving?

Comment: The value the user entered in the search box on the view

Comment: I've just tried your code, it still comes up with the same error

Comment: *The value the user entered in the search box on the view*--And what is the name of that input element?

Comment: *I've just tried your code, it still comes up with the same error* -- I would expect that because as far as I can tell, despite what you claim, that code has nothing to do with the error.  However, what was the output from the puts statements?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean what was the output? Do you mean the error message?

Comment: The puts statements print output in the server window.  Look for some lines starting with "******". Did the error occur before the puts statements could output anything?